# Displaying text in a Look-up column

Tags: list, lookup-column, custom

Apologies for not being clear. I'm try to display a "multiple lines of text" column as a look-up field in a new view of the parent list. 
I have tried SP Designer and most of the standard webparts.

Old question below:
*A user has asked if a Look-up field (‘Interdependancies’) on a custom list, can be displayed as the entire item. In this case, the look-up column is looking up another column on the same list. 
The list is used to track tasks and each item has an ID and interdependancies, consisting of other task ID’s from the same list. We want to display the interdependant tasks as a new view. 
I’ve tried SharePoint designer, but it doesn’t seem to let me show the text fields, which is the part of the item I want to show.
I can see a similar question with the answers suggesting a workflow or DataView webpart. Would this work for displaying a text field?*

Comment: Clare, I didn't understand what you trying to achieve? I got that you have a Custom List with Lookup to its own! But what do you mean by displaying entire item? Or display interdependant tasks as a new view? Can you also post a link to similar question, may be that is useful to understand... And where do you want to show the entire item? On List Forms, Views?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations as to what fields can be used as lookup columns, multiple lines of text is one that cannot be used. You might be able to pull it in as a related field though and that would be displayed along side the other information.